# Empty Table Views

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-11

I have 2 tables
demographic table and zone table. Both have data.

table demographic:
[image]

table zone:
[image]

I used:

```
Create VIEW demogzone
AS SELECT demographic.*, zone.shape_area, zone.pln_area_n, zone.geom
FROM demographic,zone
WHERE demographic.subzone=zone.subzone_n
```

The column itself get joined in the view, but the table is empty. Only header is available.
Anybody knows why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The column `subzone` in the table `demographic` has spaces, e.g.     `Airport Road` instead of `Airport Road`. So, they will never match with `zone.subzone_n`. Either join the tables using `trim()` (which might show poor performance if the table is large) ..

```
CREATE VIEW demogzone AS
SELECT demographic.*, zone.shape_area, zone.pln_area_n, zone.geom
FROM demographic
JOIN zone ON trim(demographic.subzone)=zone.subzone_n
```

Or correct it with an `UPDATE` before running your original query

```
UPDATE demographic SET subzone = trim(subzone);
```

Answer (score 1):

try "truncating"/"trim" the strings, maybe there are varying spaces after the strings. Also keep it simple with just one column as output, to see if you get a result.

Answer (score 0):

are you sure there are datasets where demographic.subzone is equal to the zone.subzone_n?? Can you maybe show simple versions of the tables?

Comment: already edited my post with screenshot of the data